# Jbossfuse amq : Send message to a queue in jbossfuse

Tags: activemq-classic, amqp, jbossfuse

I have installed Jboss-fuse, and created a amq named **test.queue.sample**

Now I want activemq-amqp-example SimpleProducer to post a message to this FUSE-amq/test.que.sample

I tried updating the jndi.properties file with appropriate broker value. but it does not connect, am I missing something? See screenshot.

## Note:

The objective is not protocol like amqp (I can change that if required). The objective is post a message to an mq configured in jboss fuse, correct connection url,  correct jndi properties etc.

## jndi.properties - updated

```
java.naming.factory.initial = org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url = src/main/resources/jndi.properties
--this line updated
connectionfactory.myJmsFactory = amqp://admin:admin@localhost/test/?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:61616'
queue.queue/simple = test.queue.simple
```

[image: JbossFuse MQ settings]

[image: avtivemq-amqp-sample: SimpleProducer.java]

[image: amq transport - uri from jboss-fuse mgmt interface]

Comment: Can you post your transport connectors from the ActiveMQ configuration file?  Most likely you are trying to hit the broker on a the wrong port.

Comment: attached screenshot of transport connectors